# Why I get this error ‘init_task’ undeclared (first use in this function)?

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to add a moudle to linux;
This is my part of my code:

```
1 #include<linux/module.h>
2 #include<linux/kernel.h>
3 #include<linux/init.h>
4 #include<linux/sched.h>  
5 #include<linux/list.h>      
6 
7 MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
8 
9 static int sched_fun_init(void)  
10 {  
11     struct task_struct *p,*ts = &init_task;
12     struct list_head *pos;
```

But I get this:

```
error: ‘init_task’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     struct task_struct *p,*ts = &init_task;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Linux kernel 4.11, variable `init_task` is declared in `linux/sched/task.h`, not in `linux/sched.h`. From [patch description](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9563245/):

> 'init_task' is really not part of core scheduler APIs but part of
>   the fork() interface between the scheduler and process management.
>
> So move the declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is undeclared.
Do you have declaraion for init_task ?

Or want to use it from init_task.c then use

```
extern struct task_struct init_task;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line：

```
#include <linux/init_task.h>
```

Answer (score -2):

Change **linux/sched.h** to **linux/sched/signal.h**

I solved the problem by this way.